# How can I increase the $R^2$ -value of my linear model? Should I increase it?

Tags: linear-model, r-squared

I'm constructing a linear model from a data set with 10 variables and my current "best" model uses 4 variables. I've tested the variables and not all of them show significance, so the most that I might add to the model might be 5 variables overall. However, with 4 and 5 variables, eventhough I get very good `Pr(>|t|)` values for all the variables that I've added and while my $R^2$ value has been improving, it's still just "only" $0.4287$ and the scale is $[0,1]$.

Should I be happy with $< 0.5$ $R^2$ value of should I aim to improve it in order to improve my model even more? What can I do to increase the $R^2$ value now that I have already added all variables that I can add as predictors? Should I look into interaction terms? Or something else?

Comment: A high Rsquared is not everything. You may have a look at a discussion R-squared versus adjusted Rsquared.

Comment: Use another criterion to adjust your model, like, AIC. This won't improve R^2 but will help variable selection.

Comment: @jchaykow How to do that in R?

Comment: @mavavilj I've done this method in my blog: http://rcode.io/work/2016-04-04-FF/ Scroll down to forward selection and backward selection.

Answer (score 1):

One common approach in these cases is to plot the train and test errors as a function of the size of your dataset. This might give some insight as to how the specific [bias variance tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff) of the algorithm you're using, is working for the particular problem.

For a specific value of *n*, generate several subsets of size *n* from your dataset. For each one, calculate the train error and test error (the latter, using the hold-out data), and record the average.

Repeat this for several values of *n*, and plot the two curves:

1. If the algorithm is suffering from high bias, then the test error will initially decrease, then settle at a relatively-fixed high value.
2. If the algorithm is suffering from high variance, there will typically remain a large gap between the train and test error.

In your case, you mention that you're using a linear predictor, so high bias is somewhat more of a suspect. If the graphs corroborate this, a good guess would be to switch to one of many higher-variance algorithms.